# Tomcat ssl аутентификация

Tags: tomcat, ssl

Стоит задача реализовать ssl аутентификацию в Tomcat.
Мои действия:

1. Создадим ключ для самого Tomcat

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias tomcat-teamcity -keystore tomcat-teamcity.jks -validity 365
   ```
2. Создаём сертификат, который будет использоваться клиентом

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias setevoy -keystore setevoy-tc.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -validity 365
   ```
3. Далее нам необходимо экспортировать публичную часть ключа, которая будет использоваться сервером для проверки валидности клиента:

   ```
   keytool -export -alias setevoy -file setevoy-tc.cer -keystore setevoy-tc.p12 -storetype PKCS12
   ```
4. Создадим хранилище для доверенных сертификатов, и добавим в него публичную часть ключа клиента

   ```
   keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias setevoy -file setevoy-tc.cer -keystore trustcacerts-teamcity.jks
   ```
5. Дополняем уже имеющуюся конфигурацию строками в `conf/server.xml`.

   ```
   Connector port="8444" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" 
    minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
    enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
    acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="tomcat-teamcity.jks"
    keyAlias="tomcat-teamcity"
    keystorePass="password"
    truststoreFile="trustcacerts-teamcity.jks"
    truststorePass="password"
   ```
6. Устанавливаем `setevoy-tc.p12` на клиенте.
7. Перезапускаем `tomcat`.
8. При попытке зайти на сайт по https.

> Ошибка подключения SSL ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Что я делаю не так?